# How to create multiple recyclerViews?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

This is not duplicate of [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)
There are question on SO for different views for different row in same list but this is not the same.

This is a very simple question as I am a beginner to android development and OOP as well.

I have multiple(three) tabs in my android app and each tab has a list of items inside it (like in whatsapp). 
I have successfully created a list(not listView) using `recyclerView` in one of the tabs. Now I want to create another list under the second tab but I have to use the previously used adapter. I don't know how to use `onCreateViewHolder()` to return multiple holders.

I tried `if(object instanceOf class)` inside `getItemViewType()` but I dont know how to access the `object` for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same adapter in all the three tabs. And for Recycler View you can use 3 different objects for those 3 tabs. This process might help in creating multiple Recycler Views.